# Import global List from another class in different python file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to read list values from another python file. but I always get empty list

A.py file

```
import time
class A(): 
   info = []
   def add_values(self):
       x = 10
       while True:
          for i in range(x):
            self.info.append(i)
          i = x
          x = x + 10
          time.sleep(3)
          if len(info)> 1000:
            return
          print self.info
    def getinfo():
        return self.info
```

B.py file

```
from A import A
Class B()

  def useinfo():
      print A.getinfo()
```

Comment: Where do you create an instance of your class A and call the instances `A().add_values()` method? Not in this code - so why would you assume it is non-empty? Beside that: `A.info != A().info`

Comment: Beside that:  `Class B()` is invalid python (missing : and capital B), `import time` is missing, `len(info)` is undefined (missing self.) etc. [mre] please

Comment: I understand every thing you talked about
I tried to use somthing like get(): return self.info, but I got empty list

Comment: Hello Patrick, I do not know how did you decided to evaluate my question with negative mark.I just added my question and you ware angry and talking with me as a student in oral exam. you did not give me several seconds to modify my code, or you do not at least gave yourself the enough time to understand what I need from my question

Comment: You came here for help. I pointed out several errors in your code that all need to be fixed to get an empty list at all. To make it clear again:if you called `def add_values(self):` anywhere, you would get an NameError preventing you to execute the code. If you started the B.py file, you would get anohter 2 errors because **`C`**lass instead of `class` and because you lack a `:`.  So essentially you want help with code that does not even do what you claim it does: giving you []. In my eyes this deserves a downvote. [edit] it so its a [mre] and the dv might vanish or even gather upvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

info is currently an instance variable on the python object, and changes to it should occur on the instance. To change add_items to update the variables in a static context. change it to be a @classmethod.

```
class A(): 
   info = []

   @classmethod
   def add_values(cls):
       x = 10
       while True:
          for i in range(x):
            cls.info.append(i)
          i = x
          x = x + 10
          time.sleep(3)
          if len(info)> 1000:
            return
          print(cls.info)
```

But it does look like you might want to create an instance of class A instead.

```
instance_of_a = A()
instance_of_a.add_values()

print(instance_of_a.info)
```

If you do want to use it as an instance variable instead of a static variable, I would change add_values to `__init__(self)` or the constructor so that way when you can just do this.

```
instance_of_a = A()
print(instance_of_a.info)
```